# Использование sizeof на неинициализированных переменных

Tags: c++, c

Можно ли использовать `sizeof()` подобным образом, ведь использование неинициализированной переменной `UB`?

```
int x;
sizeof(x);
```

Comment: А она здесь не используется... UB - это доступ к значению хранящемуся в переменной. Соответственно у неинициализированной переменной также можно брать адрес, создавать ссылки на нее, и т.п.

Comment: @VTT то есть `sizeof()` только тип смотрит и всё ок?

Comment: Да, sizeof показывает сколько байт будет занимать указанный тип или тип указанной переменной.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof` выполняется на этапе компиляции, и его результат не зависит от значения, хранимого в переменной, для которой "вызывается" `sizeof`. Более того, говорить о каких-то значениях автоматических переменных вообще нельзя до этапа выполнения программы в определённом месте. А вот для констант со статическим классом хранения, например, глобальных, это можно было бы предположить, но, как бы то ни было, результат `sizeof` от этого не зависит.

Было бы странным, если скажем для `int i = 1;` результат `sizeof(i)` отличался при использовании другого значения того же типа, например от `int i = 100500`.

Т.е. `sizeof` так или иначе вычисляет **размер типа**, несмотря на то, что может вызываться и для переменных.

Answer (score 6):

Выражение-операнд `sizeof` не является вычислимым (за редким исключением в С) и на него не распространяются требования, применяемые к вычислимым выражениям. В вашем примере неопределенного поведения нет.

Однако в языке С, если оператор `sizeof` применен к типу "массив изменяемого размера", то его выражение-операнд в общем случае *является вычислимым* и на него распространяются все обычные требования. Т.е. результат `sizeof` и его выражение-операнд в таком случае вычисляются во время выполнения.

Например, такой С код не порождает неопределенного поведения (и не пытается менять значение `i`)

```
int i;
sizeof i++;
```

Но вот такой код порождает неопределенное поведение и, если бы значение `i` было определено, увеличивал бы его на `1`

```
int i;
int n = 20;
int a[n];
int s = sizeof *(i++, &a);
```

Более компактную версию этого примера можно построить на базе `sizeof` с аргументом-типом

```
sizeof(char[i])
```

Результат этого выражения равен значению `i`. И если `i` не является константой, то данное выражение вычисляется во время выполнения и порождает неопределенное поведение при неинициализированном `i`.

Comment: А для какой цели `*` и `&` в примере?

Comment: @älёxölüt: Чтобы спасти массив от превращения в указатель. Любой массив, являющийся операндом оператора `,` превращается в указатель. Т.е. результатом `(i++, a)` является указатель. Так как указатель - это не VLA, выражение перестает быть вычислимым. Чтобы спасти "массивность" массива я прячу его за "указателем на массив" при помощи `&`, а затем в самый последний момент восстанавливаю через `*`. В таком виде `sizeof` будет применяться непосредственно к VLA и станет вычисляться во время выполнения.

Comment: Странно, но для плюсовой версии `gcc` всё равно [возвращает размер массива](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KKnVALOD9ZRmaphs). А для сишной, да, [срезает до указателя](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YyBRNjcEOyzfEuGF).

Comment: @älёxölüt: Так это следствие фундаментальнейшего отличия С++ от С: С++ старается максимально сохранить lvalue-ность выражений, а С наоборот - почти всегда сразу же превращает все в rvalue. В С++ оператор `,` сохраняет lvalue, в С оператор `,` превращает все в rvalue. Поэтому в С++ невозможно применить к массиву array-to-pointer conversion и массив остается массивом. В С же array-to-pointer conversion применяется сразу и без проблем. Фактически по той же причине в С++ можно сделать `int i[10]; int (*p)[10] = &(1, 2, 3, i);`. В С такой номер не пройдет.

Comment: Подождите-ка, что значит *"в С++ невозможно применить к массиву array-to-pointer conversion"*? А как же `int a[42]; int* b = a;` и тому подобное?

Comment: @älёxölüt: Я имею в виду, что в С++ array-to-pointer conversion невозможно применить сразу, заранее, еще при выполнении оператора `,`. В С++ оператор `,` в этом случае обязан вернуть lvalue и это lvalue обязано быть массивом. Речь идет именно и только об операторе `,`. В других контекстах (таких как ваша инициализация) array-to-pointer conversion, разумеется, будет применяться без проблем.

Comment: Другими словами, в С++ array-to-pointer conversion применяется только тогда, когда она действительно нужна. А в С array-to-pointer conversion применяется почти всегда, сразу и безусловно. (И это следствие более общего принципа: в С++ lvalue преобразуется в rvalue только тогда, когда это действительно нужно.)

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. Может быть стоит выжимку из комментариев добавить в текст ответа.